# Global operator delete - grammar

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have inherited an unchangeable C struct that contains pointers to (alloc'd) memory.

```
   typedef struct {
     int id;
     int * val;
   } T;
```

I would like to use new and delete on these objects, and I was wondering if it was possible to overload delete at global scope.  I don't have the option of rewriting the struct / class in the first place.  The trouble is I cannot find the correct grammar.  This is what I have - it compiles but obviously fails since the function is applied to all delete calls:

```
   void operator delete(void*p) throw() {
     T * t = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
     free(p->val);
   }
```

Am I attempting the impossible?  I have read that the operator delete overload does not have to be a member function, but does that just provide a means to write a generic delete for all pointers?

Comment: Good point @Tomalak and well made, but do you know what a global overload of delete looks like and how it should be used?

Comment: @youngthing. It should _never_ be used. Yuk.

Comment: Care to expand with a reason @Tomalak?

Comment: @youngthing: No, I'm a bit busy right now, hence I wrote a comment not an answer. Perhaps I will get some time later.

Comment: Hm, wish I could take back my vote-up for your original comment. @Tomalak.  The question was valid, the comments unhelpful.

Comment: @youngthing: Comment votes are for the comment that you vote on, not for arbitrary other comments later.

Comment: I don't think that the original comment was useful.

Comment: @youngthing: You shouldn't have up-voted it then.

Comment: I could flag it.  That might be thing to do.

Comment: @youngthing: You should flag abusive or spam comments. Comments that are meant to help you -- such as mine where I indicated that what you're doing is a horrendous programming idea -- are either upvoted if you like them, or left alone if you didn't. You can't just go around flagging everything you disagree with, and there is really no need to go on about it.

Comment: <quick check on meta> Fair enough.  My original flag _was_ sarcastic - and showed poor judgement.  My comment to you is that I still haven't seen anything constructive from you in the comments to either the question or any of the answers.

Comment: @youngthing: "What you're doing is a horrendous programming idea" is constructive, whether you agree with it or not. I shall no longer be participating in this discussion as I find you a little troublesome.

Comment: @Tomalak.  Yes, we finally got some content.  It has been a troublesome discussion.  However I refer to my original point that a derogatory comment added to a question without details about what is wrong or how it could be improved (or links to similar from other people) set the tone.  Bear in mind that you were the first to respond, and so your comment could not even be seen to be backing up someone else's response.  As a living community SO provides good and suitably structured space for expression, both positive and negative.  I am happy with my contribution, naive as it has been at times.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, seems like a sledgehammer approach, if you are simply a user of this structure, and worried about the memory management aspect of it, and yet cannot modify it, why don't you wrap it in your code?

i.e.

```
class Sane_T
{
  public:
   Sane_T() 
   { 
     // do stuff 
   } 

   ~Sane_T()
   {
     // Now cleanup..
     if (_inst.val)
       free(_inst.val);
   }

  private:
    T _inst;
};
```

Comment: That makes more things a lot easier - a far better design.

Comment: I am still interested in the meaning and grammar of a global operator delete, though ..

Comment: +1. This. Definitly. No "operator delete" fancy stuff. This will give you headaches: you must implement *all* the variants, and corresponding operator new. This makes 6 functions, not mentionning the array new/delete (6 more functions). See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill15.htm if you want details.

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go. No +1 though because it doesn't actually talk about the original approach and thus doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Tomalak, IMHO sometimes an explicit answer may not necessarily be the right answer to the problem at hand...

Comment: @Nim: I agree. If the answer had said "this is the answer to your question: <...> but I think, instead, you should do this: <...> because <...>" then I would have upvoted it.